# How to link multiple divs to each other and scroll them at same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML document with multiple outer and inner divs of the same classes. I also have a JQuery function which make the inner div scroll down the page. However, I can only get the function to work on the first inner div element, and not on any of the others. Here's my HTML:

```html
<div class='parent'>    
    <div class='child'>
      Val1
    </div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>    
    <div class='child'>
      Val2
    </div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>    
    <div class='child'>
      Val3
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
    .child {
    background:#ace;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

.parent {
  position:relative;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

body{
  height: 10000px;
}
```

And my JQuery:

```js
var parent = $('.parent');
var child = $('.child');
var pheight = parent.height();
var cheight = child.height();


$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if (((child.position().top + cheight) >= pheight) && ($window.scrollTop() >= (pheight + cheight))){
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('.child').followTo(pheight - cheight);
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/11879/

Essentially I want each of the "Val1", "Val2", and "Val3" divs to scroll down the page the way "Val1" currently does, but I'm not sure what the proper way to do this in JQuery is.

Comment: You're using IDs, not classes. IDs should only be applied once per document. Switch to classes.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. I must've been missing some simple syntax when I tried using classes earlier. 

But this still does not give the desired functionality, as you can see in the updated JSFiddle. How do I properly call this function to work on all of the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `child.position().top` but `child` is a **collection of your elements**.
Instead, you'd rather want to check every element's position.

Here's a slightly **different and simpler** approach:

```js
var $parent = $(".parent").each(function() {
    this._child = $(this).find(".child");
});

function fixpos() {
  $parent.each(function(){
    var br = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    $(this._child).toggleClass("sticky", br.top<0 && br.bottom>0);
  });
}

fixpos();
$(window).on("load scroll", fixpos);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{box-sizing: border-box;margin:0;}html,body{height:100%;font:16px/1 sans-serif;}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 40px; /* ADD THIS - Height of heading */
}

.child {
  background: #ace;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child.sticky { /* ADD THIS */
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Val1</div>1
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Val2</div>2
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Val3</div>3
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!